# Is this speed difference normal for http request json?

Tags: python, http, flask

I am using Flask and have a http POST and the function looks like:

```
    @api.route('/nlpjson', methods=['POST'])
    def nlpjson():
        json_data = request.get_json()
        text_data = json_data['text_data']
        #logger.info(text_data)
        parameter_data = json_data['parameter_data']
        #print(parameter_data)
        parameter_data = _get_parameter(parameter_data)
        #print(parameter_data)
    
        result = wnlu.nlpjson(text_data, **parameter_data)
        return result
```

Then I can make request like this:

```
r = requests.post("http://0.0.0.0:5000/nlpjson", json=json_data)
```

The json_data is a list of text lines. I can control how big the json_data is for each request. If for each quest I only send one line of text, it took 4 times longer than send a big chunk of text to the server for each request. Is this normal?

Is there any way I can optimize speed in my function nlpjson()?

Comment: Incase if data is too large try uploading as file instead of json data.

Comment: How to do this specifically by 'uploading as file'? Could you write an answer with some code?

Comment: I just want to be sure before answering. Are you asking why 4 requests takes longer than 1 request with all the arguments of the 4 packed up ?